# In the Benoni / Symmetric Benoni structures, what is Black supposed to do after a6/a4 is played?

Tags: opening, benoni

In the Benoni (exd5 cxd5) and Symmetric Benoni (exd5 exd5) structures, Black will often try to play a6 to try and play b5, but White can easily stop this plan with a4 / a later a5. After this happens, what is Black's plan supposed to be? I don't see any favorable pawn breaks for Black other than e6.

Comment: Could you give an example position, or better example lines? Part of the reasons is that I don't understand the last part of your question, how can Black have an e6 pawn break if he has already played exd5?

Comment: Also this might be better as two separate questions - the structures though related are definitely different, and hence will have different priorities